# How to copy additional files to OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a simple FireMonkey application which loads an image file. It's my first try with OSX. It's started on OSX via paserver from the "scratch-dir". But my image file is obviously not there and cannot be loaded. What do I have to do to make Delphi copy this image file to OSX or bundle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manually copy the image to the Resource folder into the application bundle on your Mac, your application can access the file without specifying a path.

Unfortunately, I don't know a way to get Delphi to include the file automatically.

Comment: This means I need to create a kind of installation script to create a suiteable environment on the mac to run the just compiled application.  Normally I use a "Bin"-Folder (checked in svn) as the compilation destination. In this folder all other needed files are stored. Compiling for mac I don't have this folder on the mac side, so I need to transfer it manually...I thought there would be an automatism to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Project-Deployment option to add addtional files

[image]